# Query ArangoDB general-graph for common neighbors with more than 2 start vertices?

Tags: graph, graph-algorithm, arangodb

Consider the following example graph:

[image: Graph visualization]

1. Given the vertices `A`, `B` and `C` (creators), how to figure out their common neighbors?
   (projects all 3 participated in)
   For two vertices, I could simply use `GRAPH_COMMON_NEIGHBORS("myGraph", A, B)`, but what if I want to query for 3 or more? 
   Expected result: `1` and `2`.
2. Given the same vertices, how can I make it return common neighbors with no other connections?
   (creators exclusively participated in a project, no additional edges allowed)?
   Expected result: `1`, because 2 has an edge coming from D, which isn't one of the starting vertices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply pass the same set of vertices as both parameters for common neighbors. Then repack the result in a better format for AQL to compute the intersection:

```
let res = (
  let nodes =  ["a/A","a/B","a/C"]
  for n in GRAPH_COMMON_NEIGHBORS("g",nodes , nodes) 
    for f in VALUES(n)
      return VALUES(f)
)
return CALL("intersection", res[0])
```